# How to connect to Confluent Cloud from a Docker container

Tags: scala, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have setup a Kafka topic on Confluent cloud (https://confluent.cloud/) and can connect/send messages to the topic using below configuration:

kafka-config.properties:

```
# Kafka
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
bootstrap.servers=pkc-4yyd6.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username="uname" password="pwd";
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

Connecting from a docker container I receive:

```
Failed to produce: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
```

Searching the above error suggests ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm= should fix

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ysihaoy/scala-play:2.12.2-2.6.0-sbt-0.13.15

COPY ["build.sbt", "/tmp/build/"]
COPY ["project/plugins.sbt", "project/build.properties", "/tmp/build/project/"]

COPY . /root/app/
WORKDIR /root/app

CMD ["sbt" , "run"]
```

I build and run the container using:

```
docker build -t kafkatest .
docker run -it kafkatest
```

Is there extra config required to allow connecting to Confluent Kafka ?

I do not receive this issue when building locally (not using Docker).

Update:

Here is the Scala src I use to build the properties:

```
  def buildProperties(): Properties = {

    val kafkaPropertiesFile = Source.fromResource("kafka-config.properties")

    val properties: Properties = new Properties
    properties.load(kafkaPropertiesFile.bufferedReader())
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")
    properties
  }
```

Update 2:

```
  def buildProperties(): Properties = {

    val kafkaPropertiesFile = Source.fromResource("kafka-config.properties")

    val properties: Properties = new Properties
    properties.load(kafkaPropertiesFile.bufferedReader())
    println("bootstrap.servers:"+properties.get("bootstrap.servers"))

    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")
    properties
  }
```

The property `bootstrap.servers` is found, therefore the file is added to the container.

Update3 :

```
sasl.jaas.config:org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username="Q763KBPRI" password="bFehkfL/J6m8L2aukX+A/L59LAYb/bWr"
```

Update4:

```
docker run -it kafkatest --network host
```

returns error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"--network\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to connect to Kafka please

Comment: @RobinMoffatt please see question update

Comment: Do you copy kafka-config.properties to docker image? To be sure you use correct properties, can you log them out at the end of `buildProperties` function?

Comment: @amorfis the file is added to the docker image - please see update.

Comment: Can you dump the value of `sasl.jaas.config` when you run it from Docker? A common problem is the quoting/escaping of the credentials.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt please see update3

Comment: I didn't mean quote your actual credentials on a public forum -- can you remove them please! and invalidate that API key too

Comment: @RobinMoffatt they are not correct - I've replaced the characters surrounding the slashes with false values.

Comment: OK cool, they looked too convincing :D

Comment: @blue-sky Can you try docker `run -it kafkatest --network host`? It might fix the issue.

Comment: @nbchn why Kafka test ? I'm building my own docker image that is pointing to Confluent cloud-based Kafka.

Comment: @blue-sky You said you were running the container using: "docker run -it kafkatest". Just try to add "--network host" option to that call.

Comment: @nbchn my apologies, please see update4

Comment: @blue-sky Sorry I misordered the arguments: docker run --network host -it kafkatest

Comment: @nbchn thanks but same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different base image resolved the issue, but I'm unsure which difference is causing the resolution. Here is my updated Dockerfile:

```
ARG OPENJDK_TAG=8u232
FROM openjdk:${OPENJDK_TAG}

ARG SBT_VERSION=1.4.1

# Install sbt
RUN \
  mkdir /working/ && \
  cd /working/ && \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  cd && \
  rm -r /working/ && \
  sbt sbtVersion

COPY ["build.sbt", "/tmp/build/"]
COPY ["project/plugins.sbt", "project/build.properties", "/tmp/build/project/"]

COPY . /root/app/
WORKDIR /root/app

CMD ["sbt" , "run"]
```